# What do "n" and "i" mean in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop

I'm teaching myself Swift and am sometimes able to grasp larger concepts while being unclear on details or why they work.

I figured out how to take an array and use a for loop to cycle through every third element and print them in reverse order.

**Is "n" is the element's placement in the array? What exactly is "i"?**

```
let numberArray = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten"]


func everyOther() {
    for (n, i) in numberArray.enumerated().reversed() {
         
        if (n+1).isMultiple(of: 3) {
            print(i)
        } //if
    }// for
}// func

everyOther()
```

**Thank you**

Comment: The `enumerated()` returns a sequence of tuples. Using `(n, i)` just creates a tuple with those names for each element of `numberArray`.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/arrays/how-to-loop-through-an-array-in-reverse, it is `(index, item)`

Comment: It’s actually not an *index*, but an an offset (always count up from zero). In the case of arrays the two are the same, but not for ArraySlice, Dictionary, and most other collection types. I.e. you can’t use this value to subscript into the collection to get a value out. For that you need `zip(collection.indices, collection)` instead.